# Need to Find Rare Books From File C#

Tags: c#, list

need to find a rare books from list ( rare book is a Book which are in one list and not in others) here are my list file:

```
1;Book1;name1;genre1;publisher1;2015;1000
2;Book2;name2;genre2;publisher2;2015;1000
3;Book3;name3;genre3;publisher3;2015;1000
4;Book4;name4;genre4;publisher4;2015;1000
```

next one:

```
1;Book1;name1;genre1;publisher1;2015;1000
2;Book2;name2;genre2;publisher2;2015;1000
3;Book3;name3;genre3;publisher3;2015;1000
4;Book4;name4;genre4;publisher4;2015;1000
5;Unique;name5;genre5;publisher5;2015;1250
```

in console i need to get the Unique book name but i get:

```
1, name1, Book1 , genre1 , publisher1 , 2015 , 1000
2, name2, Book2 , genre2 , publisher2 , 2015 , 1000
3, name3, Book3 , genre3 , publisher3 , 2015 , 1000
4, name4, Book4 , genre4 , publisher4 , 2015 , 1000
5, name5, Unique , genre5 , publisher5 , 2015 , 1250
```

my function code:

```
public static void RareBook(Padaliniai[] fak)
{
    List<Book> RareBooks = new List<Book>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        foreach (Book bok in fak[i].GetBookList())
        {
            RareBooks.Add(bok);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        foreach (Book a in fak[0].GetBookList())
        {
            foreach (Book b in fak[1].GetBookList())
            {
                if (a.Pav == b.Pav)
                {
                    RareBooks.Remove(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (Book bok in RareBooks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2} , {3} , {4} , {5} , {6}",bok.ISBN,bok.Autorius,bok.Pav,bok.Zanras,bok.Leidykla,bok.Metai,bok.Psl);
    }
}
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding both entries, so you need to remove both:

```
foreach (Book b in fak[1].GetBookList())
{
  if (a.Pav == b.Pav)
  {
    RareBooks.Remove(a);
    RareBooks.Remove(b);
  }
}
```

Can I just add that this is not an ideal solution? I would use some LINQ logic to do a select distinct from the union of the lists... and would override the `Book` equality methods to state when two books are the same book.

Something like this:

```
List<Book> rareBooks = fak[0].GetBookList().Except(fak[1].GetBookList())
                      .Union(fak[1].GetBookList().Except(fak[0].GetBookList()))
                      .ToList();
```

Or even this:

```
rarebooks = fak[0].GetBookList().Union(fak[1].GetBookList()).Distinct();
```

In both of the above you need to implement an `IEqualityComparer<Book>` of course.

Comment: List<T>.Remove Method (T)
Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the List<T>.

Could also use RemoveAll instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer LINQ for this kind of operation:

```
List<Book> fak0Books = fak[0].GetBookList();
List<Book> fak1Books = fak[1].GetBookList();
List<Book> rareBooks = fak0Books.Where(b0 => fak1Books.All(b1 => b0.Pav != b1.Pav)).
                                 Concat(fak1Books.Where(b1 => fak0Books.All(b0 => b0.Pav != b1.Pav)).
                                 ToList();
```

This takes all books from `fak[0]` for which there are no books with the same `Pav` in `fak[1]` and all books from `fak[1]` for which there are no books with the same `Pav` in `fak[0]`.